# Force Chromewebdriver to download text,jpg instead of opening in a new tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a need to download txt and jpg files that are basically links in a web page. I am using chrome webdriver to do the same. My code to set the chrome settings is as below:

```
 prefs = {
      :download => {:prompt_for_download => false,:default_directory => download_directory} ,
      :managed_default_content_settings => {:images => 2 },
      :webprefs =>  {:loads_images_automatically  => 'false' }
  }
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome , :prefs => prefs
```

When I click on these links, I the files opens in a new window instead of a download prompt. Is there a way to force chrome webdriver NOT to open these automatically?

Comment: Based on the discussion in [Chrome Issue 152911](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152911), I do not believe that is possible. Why not just save the contents from the newly opened window?

Comment: 1.It opens a new window and I am not sure if the new window can be handled. 2. I tried sending keys so as to save the files. I was not successful enough to save these both file types(jpg and txt) that open automatically in chrome.

Comment: Can the image and text file be accessed directly by their URL without a session (ie having to log into the website)?

Comment: I have a way to get the url of the file. But this is a https link. I used  `Net::HTTP` to download them but I was not able to. I even downloaded had the certificates loaded but I get an error `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`. I also tried different options `http.verify_mode` and also included/excluded `http.ca_file = 'D:\certificate\certificate.cer'     # Location of certificate file`

Comment: These files get generated dynamically and are valid only for that session of the browser.